# Recurrence relation - 2 consecutive 0s

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a question about this question:
[Recurrence relation find the number of binary strings that contain two consecutive zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261478/recurrence-relation-find-the-number-of-binary-strings-that-contain-two-consecuti)

In your answer,

> No, it takes each bit separately, except for the last two. It says the
>   string can end in 00,01,10,11. If it ends in 00 it is acceptable
>   regardless of what came before-that is the 2n−2. If it ends in
>   anything else, it must have been acceptable before, or have the 00
>   come from the addition. Adding a 1 can never make a string acceptable,
>   so you can add it to the end of an−1 strings. We still haven't
>   accounted for the ones that end in 10, and that is the an−2.

I'm a little confused about why the case '11' is counted in the a(n-1) case but not the a(n-2) case. Can you not also add '11' to the end of any a(n-2) string and maintain that the string before still has substring '00'?

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 1):

We can account for $11$ in the $a_{n-2}$, case but it makes the $a_{n-1}$ case harder to deal with. Here's what would happen:

We have $4$ endings we can add to an $n-2$ length string to get to an $n$ length string: $00,01,10$, and $11$. Of these, the $10$ case and the $11$ case can't add any consecutive $0$s, so together they give us $2a_{n-2}$ valid strings. As in the other construction the $00$ case gives us a $2^{n-2}$ term (since it doesn't matter what the previous digits were). Finally, we are left with the $01$ case. This case is a little tricky to deal with because it will not just give us $a_{n-1}$ strings because we have the additional restriction that the last digit of the $n-1$ length string is a $0$. Okay, so how many valid strings of length $n-1$ are there whose last digit is $0$?. Well, as we had before the number of valid length $n-1$ stings whose last digit is $1$ is just $a_{n-2}$. Hence the number of valid $n-1$ length string who end in $0$ is $a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$. This gives us the recurrence relation
$$a_n=2a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+2^{n-2}=a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+2^{n-2}$$
which is exactly what we had before except it took a bit more work.

The idea in the original solution is to avoid this difficulty by working backwards. First, if we add a $1$ to a valid $n-1$ length string, we get a valid $n$ length string, so we get an $a_{n-1}$ term (note here we are dealing with both the $01$ and $11$ cases because we are just requiring that the last digit be $1$). This leaves us with the $10$ and $00$ cases. The $00$ case we immediately deal with as before (getting a $2^{n-2}$ term). The $10$ case now just gives us a term of $a_{n-2}$ since we can't add any consecutive $0$s by adding $10$. Putting this into a recurrence relation gives us exactly the same thing as above, but we avoid having to cancel any terms.