# Asymptotic Behaviour of higher order linear recurrence

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I am interested in a approximative asymptotic behaviour of the following recurrence of the number $N_p(m,l)$ of $p$-ary sequences of length $m$, which do not contain $l$ consecutive zeros (Runlength limited sequences):

$$\begin{equation}
p^0+p^1z+p^2z^2+...+p^{l-1}z^{l-1}+\sum_{m=l}^{\infty}\left[ (p-1) \sum_{i=1}^{l} N_p(m-i,l) 
 \right]z^m
\end{equation}$$

The first $l$ coefficients are initial conditions, since for $m<l$ the number of the RLL sequences is simply $p^m$. For $m \geq l$ the number $N_p(m,l)$ is the sum of the previous $l$ terms multiplied by $(p-1)$, which we see in the sum term in the recurrence.

For binary (p=2) words and $l=2$ the recurrence turns out to be Fibonacci numbers, where the asymptotic behaviour for large lengths $m$ is known.

I hope, that someone could lead me to an approximative asymptotic behaviour for the genereal case $p$ and $l$. The best would be, to have an analytic function of $p,l$ and $m$ for the asymptotic behaviour without numeric ways like finding the dominant singularity or so.

Thank You!